# in jquery callback function call twice how to avoid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write API call its hit the database but in this code callback operation call multiple time so please try understand my  question 
 in this below code is not working properly please correct it

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // reject article requests start
  var article;
  $(".resend-article-request").click(function() {
    var articleId = $(this).attr("data-article-id");
    article = articleId;
    $("#articleRejectModal").foundation('open');

  });

  $(".editingReasons").click(function() {
    var formData = new FormData($('#articleEditForm')[0]);
    formData.append('articleId', article)
    var articleReviewCallBacks = {
      "success": function(data) {
        $('#articleEditForm')[0].reset();
        alert("Sending for Re-Write article.");
        window.location.reload();
      },
      "error": function(data) {
        alert("error");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    };
    window.pmprojectutils.getResponse('POST', '/api/article/rewrite', formData, articleReviewCallBacks, true);
  })
});
```

Comment: Can you please provide a JsFiddle to be able to help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pu6t15jq/1/

Comment: Okay, and what exactly do I need to do? I don't get it ... I can write text and then? It seems that there are some elements missing, right?